# How to drop only DHCP packets between two bridges?

Tags: iptables

I have a broadband ADSL modem-router SagemCom F@st 2704 which has a lot of embeded options such as create different networks per interface ( 4 Ethnet ports and 5 Wireless SSID, and many over fonctionnalyties). 
He has also an **Interface Grouping** fonction in it's web interface wich permit to brigde single or multiple interfaces together.
In order to separate interfaces and have two differents DHCP-servers on them, i have create two bridges **br0** and **br1** as shown on picture below:

**br0**= ( eth0, eth1, wl0) and 
**br1**= ( eth2, eth3, wl0.1)

So, this is my **Telnet** interfaces:

```
atm0, atm0.1, atm0.2, bcmsw, br0, br1, eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3, lo, ppp1.1, wl0, wl0.1, wl0.2, wl0.3, wl0.4
```

I have try some kind of firewall instructions with **ebtables** commande but it's doesn't work. This is my commandes:

```
ebtables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o br1 -d ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff -j DROP
ebtables -A FORWARD -i br1 -o br0 -d ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff -j DROP
```

Please, how to separate the brigdes **br0** and **br1** in order to **only** DROP all DHCP communications between them ?

Comment: If you want two separate networks, delete the bridge and create routes between the two networks.

Comment: thank for your reply. but, is routes the network means something like
`route add inet_1 mask_1 getway `

Comment: But it's impossible to create networks without bridges interfaces !
Is there another way to do it with bridged interfaces ?

Comment: You are mistaken. Bridges join two networks at the Layer 2 level. You want to join two networks at the Layer 3 level, which requires *routing*.

Comment: You're right ! The correct word is **Group interfaces**. But, with this router, when you group one or more interfaces, it create automatically a **br**x interface and give it another **network** ip adresse for this **br**x group.

The problem is that when i connect a dhcp server, different to which is binding normally by the router, to one group, the other hosts on others groups (network) **receive their ip** from the first one.

How does dhcp trames get to join others networks throw the router ?
This is all mistake for me.
I have to DROP these packets. But how, i don't know... please help me.

Comment: Get a professional grade router.